# Assembly (NASM) - User inputs six numbers to add and subtract

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I got the first sum to work, but the last two sums are broken. I can't figure out why.
The input should look like this (all on separate lines), with no inputted numbers exceeding 10:

```
4 + 2
7 - 2
3 + 2
```

This is my code:

```
;this program adds and subtracts


section .data 
    ; used for printing new lines
    newline db 10
 
section .bss
    ;registers for their numbers, their operators, and their sums
    num1 resb 2 
    op resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    sum resb 1
    
    num3 resb 2
    op2 resb 2
    num4 resb 2
    sum2 resb 1
    
    blankspace1 resb 2
    num5 resb 2
    op3 resb 2
    num6 resb 2
    sum3 resb 1
    
section .text

; similar to a function in C++, used to print 
print_int:
    mov eax, 4  ;defining routine print_int
    mov ebx, 1  ;file descriptor (stdout)
    int 0x80    ;system call number (sys_write)
    ret     ;return back

   
global _start   
_start:

;reads & saves user input for num1
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num1
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

;reads & saves user input for first operator
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, op
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

;reads & saves user input for num2
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num2
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h




;reads & saves user input for num3
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num3
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h




;reads & saves user input for second operator
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, op2
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h


;reads & saves user input for num4
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num4
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

;reads & saves user input for the blankspace/newline empty space
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, blankspace1
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h


mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, blankspace1
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

;reads & saves user input for num5
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num5
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h


;reads & saves user input for third operator
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, op3
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

;reads & saves user input for num6
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num6
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h



;Add num1 and  num2
mov al, [num1]
;we must use subratact 0 so it's saved as a number, not a character/string
sub al, '0'           
mov bl, [num2]
sub bl, '0'

add al, bl 

;load sum to to be printed
mov edx,2 
mov ecx, sum
cmp al, 10
jb  SingleDigit


 mov byte [ecx], '1'
 inc ecx          ;Move to position for the units/newline
 inc edx          ;String length if double digit sum
 sub al, 10       ;Only keep the units

SingleDigit:
 add al, '0'      ;From number 0-9 to character '0'-'9'
 mov [ecx], ax


 mov ecx, sum
call print_int

mov cl, [num3]
sub cl, '0'
mov dl, [num4]
sub dl, '0'
sub dl, cl

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, newline
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

;load sum to to be printed
mov edx, 2 
mov ecx, sum2
cmp dl, 10
;jb  SingleDigit2



;SingleDigit2:
 add dl, '0'      ;From number 0-9 to character '0'-'9'
 mov [ecx], dx


mov ecx, sum2
call print_int


mov bl, [num5]
sub bl, '0'
mov cl, [num6]
sub cl, '0'                       

add bl, cl


mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, newline
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

;load sum to to be printed
mov edx,2 
mov ecx, sum3
cmp bl, 10
jb  SingleDigit3



SingleDigit3:
 add bl, '0'      ;From number 0-9 to character '0'-'9'
 mov [ecx], bx


 mov ecx, sum3
call print_int
    
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

Comment: Broken how?  What is the actual output / result?  Include that to make a [mcve].What did you see when you single-stepped through your code with a debugger like GDB?    Did you try it with inputs that produce an output outside 0..9? Your `print_int` function is actually just a `write` system call to stdout, with buffer and length in ecx and edx respectively, and I think your callers just assume single-digit output.  So of course that would break.

Comment: Subtraction is not commutative, so the order between the operands matter. I also don't understand what the point is of storing the operators individually if you're not using them for anything.

Comment: And you seem to disregard the fact that `dl` is a part of `edx`, and that `bl` is a part of `ebx`.